# ReactToastify position not working in React

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-toastify

toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css` and I can't manage the Toast to show in the bottom right. I'm using the exact code as the documentation. But it's not working

```
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css'; 
toast.configure();

function myComponent () {
   
   ...
   const submit = () => {
       toast.success('Your Message was sent to Wasfa Team', { poistion: toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_RIGHT });
   }
   ...
   return (
     ...
     <ToastContainer />
   )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the position as a prop on `ToastContainer`

```
<ToastContainer position="bottom-right" />
```

Answer (score 2):

just use the position

```
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css'; 
toast.configure();

function myComponent () {
   
   ...
   const submit = () => {
       toast.success('Your Message was sent to Wasfa Team', { poistion: "bottom-right" });
   }
   ...
   return (
     ...
     <ToastContainer />
   )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set position attribute

```
   <ToastContainer position="bottom-right"/>
```